# Como crear un Objeto a partir de un fichero JSON

Tags: java, json, arraylist

Pues quería saber ¿cómo puedo crear un objeto con varios parámetros que vienen a partir de un fichero JSON?

Llevo esto:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive;

public class LeerJson {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    try {
        FileReader lector = new FileReader("src\\com\\dinaprise\\lectura\\json\\JsonPrueba.json");
        JsonElement datos = parser.parse(lector);
        dumpJSONElement(datos);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}

private static void dumpJSONElement(JsonElement elemento) {
    ArrayList<String> datos = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (elemento.isJsonObject()) {
        // Conjunto de pares clave y valor
        System.out.println("Es objeto");
        JsonObject obj = elemento.getAsJsonObject();
        java.util.Set<java.util.Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> entradas = obj.entrySet();
        java.util.Iterator<java.util.Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> iter = entradas.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            java.util.Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entrada = iter.next();
            System.out.println("Clave: " + entrada.getKey() + " ");
            dumpJSONElement(entrada.getValue());
        }

    } else if (elemento.isJsonArray()) {
        // Utilizado para si el archivo json es un array de elementos simples o
        // compuestos
        JsonArray array = elemento.getAsJsonArray();
        System.out.println("Es array. Numero de elementos: " + array.size());
        java.util.Iterator<JsonElement> iter = array.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            JsonElement entrada = iter.next();
            dumpJSONElement(entrada);
        }
    } else if (elemento.isJsonPrimitive()) {
        // Elementos primitivos, determina si el valor es booleano numero o cadena de
        // texto
        JsonPrimitive valor = elemento.getAsJsonPrimitive();
        if (valor.isBoolean()) {
            System.out.println(valor.getAsBoolean() + " ");
        } else if (valor.isNumber()) {
            System.out.println(valor.getAsNumber() + " ");
        } else if (valor.isString()) {
            System.out.println(valor.getAsString() + " ");
            datos.add(valor.getAsString());
        }
    } else if (elemento.isJsonNull()) {
        // Comprueba que no sea null
        System.out.println("Es NULL");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Es otra cosa");
    }
    String[] dato = new String[datos.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < datos.size(); i++) {
        dato[i] = datos.get(i);
    }

}

}
```

Adjunto el fichero JSON

```
{
    "Agencia": [
        {
        "strCod": "000001",
        "strNombreAgencia": "SEUR",
        "strCP": "14700",
        "strPob": "PALMA DEL RIO",
        "strProv": "CORDOBA",
        "strTipoVia": "CALLE",
        "strNomVia": "SOL",
        "strNumVia": "3",
        "strPiso": "BAJO",
        "strLetra": "A"
        },
        {
        "strCod": "000002",
        "strNombreAgencia": "MRW",
        "strCP": "14700",
        "strPob": "PALMA DEL RIO",
        "strProv": "CORDOBA",
        "strTipoVia": "AVENIDA",
        "strNomVia": "GOYA",
        "strNumVia": "3",
        "strPiso": "NULL",
        "strLetra": "NULL"
        }
    ]
}
```

Todo esto lo pinta, pero ¿cómo puedo crear un objeto del tipo *agencia* obteniendo los atributos del JSON?

Un saludo

Comment: Lo que necesitas no es más que una Lista de elementos `Agencia` . Puedes usar [esta herramienta](https://jsonutils.com/) para comprobarlo

Comment: No se a que te refieres con eso, porque aunque yo creo una lista agencia cuando hago esto: List<Agencia> agencias; agencias.add(new Agencia()); como meto los datos como atributos dentro del parentesis del new Agencia?

Answer (score 1):

Como te comentaba, usando https://jsonutils.com/ puedes generar automáticamente las clases que debe rellenar. Por simplicidad he omitido los getters y setters:

```
public class Agencia {
    private String strCod;
    private String strNombreAgencia;
    private String strCP;
    private String strPob;
    private String strProv;
    private String strTipoVia;
    private String strNomVia;
    private String strNumVia;
    private String strPiso;
    private String strLetra;

    // ... aquí irían los getters y setters
}

public class Base {
    private List<Agencia> agencia;

    public setAgencia(List<Agencia> l) {
        this.agencia=l;
    }
    public List<Agencia> getAgencia() {return this.agencia;}
}
```

Usando Gson es muy sencillo rellenar estos objetos:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

try (Reader reader = new FileReader("JsonPrueba.json")) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Agencia>>() { }.getType(); 
    Reader reader = new FileReader("src\\com\\dinaprise\\lectura\\json\\JsonPrueba.json"); 
    List<Agencia> dato = gson.fromJson(reader, listType); 

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Nota**: código final recogido de los comentarios del OP.

Comment: Una vez hecho lo que me has dicho los valores que introducen son null y no entiendo el porque

Comment: ¿Qué valores son null? ¿añadiste los getters y setters?

Comment: Vale ya lo arregle lo pongo en comentarios para el que lo necesite Gson gson = new Gson();
  Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Agencia>>() {
  }.getType();
  Reader reader = new FileReader("src\\com\\dinaprise\\lectura\\json\\JsonPrueba.json");
  List<Agencia> dato = gson.fromJson(reader, listType);
  dato.toString();